# Simple Javascript code to strip out characters from a field

Tags: javascript

It is interesting that I probably did 100 searches and every result assumes that you already know how to use Javascript and only provides a fraction of the code.  I do not need JQuery, I just need a simple javascript code that removes parenthesis and a dollar sign from a form field so that I can copy and paste text that is displayed as ($-45.00) for example, I want it to strip out to read just -45.00 and remove the dollar sign and parenthesis. I actually need the HTML part of the code to use in the field

I tried multiple codes and nothing works

```
<input name="amnt[]" type="text" value="-" size="9" maxlength="12" />
```

I found some code on this site like this that seems to do what I want:

```
run1.onclick = function() {
  //removes "(" and ")"
  output1.innerHTML = input1.value.replace(/[()]/g, ''); 
}
```

but it wants you to click a button for it to work and I want it to appear in the value field automatically.

The codes I found online have no result good or bad.  I am not a coder I just need to add this simple change to my website that I use for personal use and I'll probably never edit it again.

If anything can anyone give me a link to a website that actually displays the FULL code to do things like this all my results are stackoverflow partial codes that do not help me.  That is like buying a car and they only give you a steering wheel I need more than that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype - tried replace?

Comment: Thanks for replying but I don't even know which HTML code needed to add to that field to make it generate the Javascript.  Most searches just show a line of code and I don't know how to use the code for it to work fully.

Comment: I tried reading w3schools I work seven days a week 12 hours a day and I tried learning it for a week and cannot figure it out.  I am a older guy and I learned its best to ask or pay someone else who already put in all of the expertise to do it right instead of getting a migraine

Comment: "That is like buying a car and they only give you a steering wheel I need more than that."  You didn't buy the car.  You effectively walked into a community center of people you don't know and demanded that they do your job for you.  Many of us here on Stack Overflow are very happy to help people get started.  I particularly like to help beginners.  It's great to be able to teach people, explain how things work, and then they can go on to be effective and teach others.  You're not interested in learning... therefore we (or, at least I) have no interest in helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code Snippet using Regex to strip:

```js
function getResult() {
var oData = document.getElementById("elem_id").value;
var oMatch = /(?:\(\$([\d-.]+)\))/g.exec(oData);
console.log(oMatch);
document.getElementById("elem_id").value = (oMatch == null ? oData : oMatch[1]);

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="elem_id" onblur="getResult();" value="-" size="9" maxlength="12"/>
```

Comment: Freakin sweet this worked thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="elem_id" name="amnt[]" type="text" value="-" size="9" maxlength="12" oninput="myFunction()" />
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var element = document.getElementById("elem_id");
            var inputStr = element.value;
            inputStr = inputStr.replace("(", "");
            inputStr = inputStr.replace(")", "");
            inputStr = inputStr.replace("$", "");
            element.value = inputStr;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

`elem_id` is your input field id.

Update :-
Here is the optimized way :-

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="elem_id" name="amnt[]" type="text" value="-" size="9" maxlength="12" oninput="myFunction()" />
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction(event) {
            var element = document.getElementById("elem_id");
            var inputStr = element.value;
            inputStr = inputStr.replace(/[()$]/g, "");
            element.value = inputStr;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this removes the $ character, per the question.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: It seems to work but for some reason it will not work when I add it to a particular page so I have to do more research on why that is but if it works I will be sure to give you the solved checkmark thanks

Comment: make sure your input element id is correct and check your other scripts for any interferences. And also try using this script in ```<head></head>``` part of your page. And research more

Comment: Yes I have a separate javascript file for my functions there in the header.  There has to be something else conflicting with it since it wont work on the web page but your code works on a blank file on the website.  I understand about the form ID having to match.  This is why I could never learn Javascript.  I know PHP simple code you add it and you are done.

Comment: Yeah something else must be preventing it to work I give up

Comment: Try posting a question with your scripts and html. It might help

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time.  The code below using the onblur seems to work.

Comment: I also wanted to let you know that I tried it with your code and works too. The onblur is what is making it work now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to do this:

HTML:

```
<input id="example-id" name="amnt[]" type="text" value="-" size="9" maxlength="12" />
```

Javascript:

```
let valueField = document.getElementById("example-id");
valueField.onchange = function(){
  valueField.value = valueField.value.replace(/[()\$]/g, "");
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mp3yq1x9/) of this in action.